# Does Java Bytecode have to follow Java syntax structure?

Tags: java, bytecode

Java has some rigid rules on the source files it is structured in, such as the need to have only one class per file in files with the same name.
And javac compiles each source file in a Bytecode `.class` file.
My question is, other languages exist which compile to Java Bytecode and does not have a rigid structure as Java (Scala, some versions of Ruby), do the Bytecode files need to be generated in a class file hierarchy even if the source code is not?

**UPDATE**
I'm not talking about the approach to JVM's, i'm talking about whether Bytecode files must follow the structure of the Java source files (one class for each file) or it's open to other structures. The file specification does not say anything about it.

Comment: Java does not compile each source file into a single bytecode file. Your question is based on a false premiss.

Comment: That's not what I said, I said each source file in a .class file. It wouldn't even make sense a single class file for the entire program

Comment: I think EJP's point was that javac compiles each source file into at least one, but possibly multiple, class files. Every class in the source (including inner classes, anonymous classes, all of 'em) gets its own class file.

Comment: @yshavit: to be nitpicking, there is no requirement that a `.java` source file actually contains a class. So source files are not compiled into “*at least one*” class file, but just an arbitrary number of class files.

Comment: @Holger Yes, I would agree that's a nitpick. ;) It has so be a non-negative integer number, too.

Comment: @yshavit: I’m not sure whether it is specified anywhere that the number of generated class files must be non-negative…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bytecode file contains exactly one class. This is prescribed by JVM spec. If you want to keep many classes in a single file, standard solution is to pack them in a .jar file, which is effectively a .zip file.

Java source files, in contrary, may contain multiple classes. However, there can be at most one public top-level class in the source file.

Comment: So if I have to compile some non-Java source code into Java Bytecode I'm forced to create a "fake class"? I mean, if I have a global variable in a package, I have to create a class for that variable and put it as static field to translate it into a class file?

Comment: yes, or put that variable in any other existing class.

Comment: Even Java places package global information into pseudo classes, i.e. `package-info.class`, though they don’t contain global variables, but e.g. package annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which specification you are referring to, but the one from Oracle makes it **very** clear that there is exactly **one** class within each class file (besides: why do you think they are called **class** files).

Quoting from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html):

*A class file consists of a **single** ClassFile structure:*

```
ClassFile {
u4             magic;
u2             minor_version;
u2             major_version;
u2             constant_pool_count;
cp_info        constant_pool[constant_pool_count-1];
u2             access_flags;
u2             this_class;
u2             super_class;
u2             interfaces_count;
u2             interfaces[interfaces_count];
u2             fields_count;
field_info     fields[fields_count];
u2             methods_count;
method_info    methods[methods_count];
u2             attributes_count;
attribute_info attributes[attributes_count];
}
```

So, very much obviously: one such struct per class file; and exactly one class denoted by such a struct.

And just for the record: if you really intend to work on a compiler that is supposed to create valid bytecode files ... then you need to be much more diligent. This kind of work is kinda **advanced**; and you are already stumbling at the very first step.

Answer (score -3):

If it's Java Bytecode, it's ordered in such a way that any JVM (Java Virtual Machine) can understand it.

If any JVM that obeys the standards can't run your Java Bytecode, then it's not Java Bytecode.

JVM's come in many forms (Sun/Oracle, IBM, Google, etc), but they're only truely Java if they can run ALL Java code on ALL platforms.

The answer is no. If the Java Specification doesn't allow it, no JVM should, either.

Comment: I'm not talking about the approach to JVM's, i'm talking about whether Bytecode files must follow the structure of the Java source files (one class for each file) or it's open to other structures. The file specification does not say anything about it.

Comment: that's exactly what I was talking about. Bytecode must obey Java Specs, or it's no longer Java.

Comment: The question is about bytecode that could even emancipate from Java, and Java that is "just a language that can compile to Bytecode". So that the Java Bytecode may not be necessarily "Java". Scala, for example, compiles to JVM Bytecode but has nothing to do with Java